# Move Ubuntu Server 14.04 from 128 to 256 GB SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a 250 GB Samsung Evo which I plan to use to replace my old 128 OCZ SSDrive in my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. Obvously I don't want to reinstall everything and as I'm just moving from one SSD to another, shouldn't I be able to clone the data? 
I found here
https://radu.cotescu.com/migrating-your-ubuntu-machine-to-a-ssd-drive/ a post that suggestes using gddresuce, would that be suitable?

From what I understand it does a bit by bit copy, including the boot sector and everything? And afterwards i could extend the partion to the whole SSD size?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so, most of them relying on dd and resize2fs behind some frontend if you don't want to do it manually. I would recommend CloneZilla, which will also resize your partitions and write new partition table.

Answer (score 0):

There is many approachs..
For now I only describe one method.
1) 
Run a live distro of Ubuntu from CD or USB.
Backup your system (Ubuntu) ext partition and other partitions contain any data,except boot or any small partitions designed for your bootloader.generally these are at the very beginning of disk.
You can use ubuntu's built-in tools like gnome-disks or gparted to backup (copy).
If you are able to attach both source and destination drives to a Live-running system then there's no need to backup, and just copy these partitions to second disk.
Make sure there's enough empty space between destination partitions if you need to enlarge them later and about 1GB of space at very beginning of second disk for creating boot partition.
(Hint:We don't copy boot partitions because there's some codes in it point to exact UID of each partition that is meaningful only for first disk)
2) better you enlarge (expand) your partitions right after previous step.
Create new partitions or expand them to your desired size
3) Run live version of boot-repair disk..
Or any live ubuntu disk with pre-installed boot-repair application.
However this step is a bit geeky to perform.
Try to repair your grub bootloader with these tools. Don't worry about loosing your data as long as there's backups of partitions.
Your bootloader will be ok for sure.
PS. Don't forget to remain some storage for swap partition (about 1.5 to 2 times of your RAM,if you need it)